# How can I disable window.onbeforeunload using jQuery class click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a button that toggles a new class when it's clicked, then when that new class is clicked, it sets goAway to true. Here's what I'm using, does anyone notice something that would prevent this? It works in all other onclick functions that have the line: goAway = true;

```
var goAway = false;  

$("button:not(.MyNewClass)").click(function(){
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
if (!goAway) {
return 'Syanara mutha ******';
        }
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.MyNewClass').click(function() {
        goAway = true;
    });
});
```

I have also tried this below, but neither seem to work...

```
var goAway = false;  

$("button:not(.MyNewClass)").click(function(){
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
if (!goAway) {
return 'Syanara mutha ******';
        }
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.MyNewClass').click(function() {
       window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I figured it out. Attached a JavaScript onClick event to the element set to toggle with jQuery ;)

The html button:

```
<button onclick="removeWarning()">This is the button</button>
```

Then the rest:

```
<script>
var goAway = false;  
$("button").click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('MyNewClass');
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
if (!goAway) {
return 'Syanara mutha ******';
        }
    }
});
function removeWarning(){
if ($("button").hasClass('MyNewClass')){
goAway = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try either one of this.

**First one:**

```
$(window).unbind('onbeforeunload');
```

**Second one:**

```
window.onbeforeunload = false;
```

I hope this works for you.

**Update**:
I noticed you placed `onbeforeunload` function inside `click` function.
Once try by placing this function out side of click function.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (!goAway) {
        return 'Syanara mutha ******';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck. It seems like all the stuff that typically work doesn't work if I've enabled window.onbeforeunload previously. Not sure why that would happen though.

Comment: This is because I don't want this to be the default behavior, I only want the warning to appear after they have clicked the button. Then I want the second click of the same button, to disable that ;).

Basically, the page is several layers deep using jQuery toggles. If they toggle back to the start, I don't want them to be warned if leaving. Only if they hit back once they started but have not navigated back.